# push notification feedback service

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, feedback

I can send push notification to iphone success with certificate `ck.pem` throught `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` in development environment.

But I want to access `feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com`, I got the error as follow:

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iphone/freebackFromApple.php on line 8
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iphone/freebackFromApple.php on line 8
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 (Unknown error) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iphone/freebackFromApple.php on line 8
>   Failed to connect feedback server: 0

My php code as follows:

```
<?php

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iphone/share/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
    print "Failed to connect feedback server: $error $errorString\n";
    return;
else {
    print "Connection to feedback server OK\n";
}

print "APNS feedback results\n";
while ($devcon = fread($fp, 38)) {
    $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon);
    $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));
    $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8));
    $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime);
    $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4));
    $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);
    print "TIMESTAMP:" . $feedbackDate . "\n";
    print "DEVICE ID:" . $feedbackDeviceToken . "\n\n";
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Apple's provisioning website to try download the certificates to combine to ck.pem again, then put it to Your Server site.
It works for me, ya.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a certificate error. Have you checked on Apple's provisioning website whether your SSL certificates are up to date?

You also have to specify the keyfile, beside the certfile.